# Read/Write lock required when writing to a std::map<K, V> in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, unordered-map, readwritelock

I've implemented a systemd service in C++ that automatically starts when the system boots. The goal of this service is to acquire system resources and make them accessible via an API.

One of these resources is the cpu load. I've implemented a separate thread that reads the information from '/proc/stat' in a set interval (each second) and simultaneously calculates the cpu load from these readings. The readings are stored in an `std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t>` and the values are read from the main program whenever the API is called.

I've read that I should use a read/write lock when writing and reading from the same container in different threads. Is this assumption correct?

How would I implement such a read/write lock?

The values of the map are directly written by specifying the key:
`my_map['some_key'] = value`

What would happen if i lock the container with a read lock and the separate thread tries to write simultaneously? Since new values are written each second, that might be problematic.

Comment: yes, you need it. with 1/sec transactions you'll likely be ok (unless you force yourself into a deadlock), simply you won't get the write lock while the read lock is active.

Comment: for a `uint32_t` you won't need a read lock, only a write lock, just make sure you don't accidentally edit the map when you are reading from it, ie: check a variable exist before trying to read its value, but if you have a more complicated struct then a read/write lock will be necessary.

Comment: @AhmedAEK If a read-write lock is used, then a read lock is required to avoid a race condition while a write is done. There is no guarantee uint32 access will be atomic on all platform (in fact, there are some platform that are not atomic like embedded ARM devices). x86-64 guarantee that but not the standard. This is also required when a resize is done or a new value is added.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that I should use a read/write lock when writing and reading from the same container in different threads. Is this assumption correct?

This is not the only option but this is a good choice in this case. A basic lock can work but it will be slower (it will serialise reads here while reads needs to be fast and this is not a problem if writes are slow in your case).

> How would I implement such a read/write lock?

In C++17, there is a [`shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) class implementing such a mechanism. The `shared` access mode is for the readers and the `exclusive` access mode is for the writers.

> What would happen if i lock the container with a read lock and the separate thread tries to write simultaneously?

If the thread writing in the container do not lock a write lock of the read-write mutex, then there is a race condition causing an undefined behaviour (eg. crash). With a read-write lock, the writes to the container will be mutually exclusive (ie. safe). The same ting happens between the reads and writes but not between multiple reads.